# How do I conclude that there exists a nonzero element satisfying this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $O_K$.

Let $c$ be a positive real number and $n$ be a positive integer.

Suppose for each $t>c$, there exists a nonzero $a\in I$ such that $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)|\leq (t/n)^n$.

How do I conclude that there exists a nonzero $a\in I$ such that $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)|\leq (c/n)^n$?

Why is it not possible that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ takes its value densely greater than $(c/n)^n$?

Comment: So $n$ is useless

Comment: For $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ then $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)| = \# \mathcal{O}_K/(a)$ (the ideal norm is the absolute value of the field norm)

Comment: @reuns Yes, maybe. This is just my situation. You may take the right-hand-side as a function $f(t)$ which depend on $t$ with some extra condition such as continuity maybe?

Comment: Yes I know that the absolute norm is a generalization of the field norm. How does that help?

Comment: I should have said instead $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)|$ is an integer so  $|N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)|  \le c+\epsilon \implies |N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)| \le \lfloor c+\epsilon \rfloor$

Comment: Oh right. I now get it. Thank you!

Comment: And I was writing a proof that the field norm is the ideal norm if you want it

Comment: It is fine because I know that one :) Indeed, the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed suffices to prove that the field norm is integer valued on $O_K$.

Comment: Integrally closed isn't really the problem. With an integral basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$ you obtain $\varphi:\mathcal{O}_K  \to\mathbb{Z}^n$ an isomorphism of additive groups. If $a \in\mathcal{O}_K$ then $\varphi(a \mathcal{O}_K)= A \mathbb{Z}^n$ for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$. And hence as quotient of abelian groups $$N(a \mathcal{O}_K)=\# \mathcal{O}_K/a\mathcal{O}_K = \# \mathbb{Z}^n / A \mathbb{Z}^n = |\det(A)| = |N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)| $$ where $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(a)$ is defined as $\det(A)$. Note how $\det(A)$ stays the same if we consider a subring $R$ such that $K = Frac(R)$